# Avr atmega 16 with webcam

Tags: arduino, avr, atmel

I want use the webcam for image capturing and interface that web cam with avr atmega 16. Since the images are big in size where should I store the data. And secondly, Since the webcam gives the images in a form of file format how can i decode that file format and store the details in a particular storage medium?

Thankyou in advance

Comment: In short: don't. That's an 8 bit microcontroller without USB, with no DMA and only 20MHz clock rate - in summary, not suitable for image processing let alone acquisition. Your assertions about how USB webcams work are also wrong - they know nothing of files or file formats. If you had stated what you were trying to solve we could perhaps have suggested a realistic alternative.

Comment: @YannVernier  i was actually confused with file formats. But i found if i have bmp file format i can easily read out pixels and use images but yes you are right that avr atmega16 is too slow to do image processing. Thankyou for your support

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I can use the sd card for my solution. I found the blog over the internet that showed how to interface arduino with webcam